# dpkg custom package name from source install

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg, source

I want to be able to set a custom package name when installing a package using dpkg from source.  Running this command:

`dpkg -i /path/to/deb/ruby-2.2.0.deb`

installs the package as:

`ruby-2.2.0 2.2.0`

I'd like to have this install as just ruby, since the version is listed in the next column anyway.  Would help out with writing some serverspec tests.  I've checked the man for dpkg but don't see it as an option there.  Is this possible?

Comment: why do you need to deviate from the OS stablished naming convention in this way? what problem does it solve? are you aware that there are other `ruby` versions available and that you can choose the default by using the [update-alternatives](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) system?

Comment: I'm in the process of writing some serverspec tests and one of the specs to check if a particular version of ruby is installed seems redundant.  Right now, it looks like ```describe package ('ruby-2.2.0') do
  it { should be_installed have_version('2.2.0')}
end```

Comment: didn't mean to post that so soon, here's what I left out:...where the version is not needed in the first line.  I'd prefer it to be in the `have_version` line.  Also, don't want multiple versions of ruby on our servers.  I do use rbenv to manage mulitple ruby versions in development on my workstation however.